# jquery- Need to check if a file was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I need to trigger an event if a file is loaded and not if they cancel from the browse and dont upload a file.

If I check the value of the file immediately after I click upload it will always be empty.  How can I check after the browse has been closed?
Thanks in advance

```
<input type="file"
    name="uploadFileButton" id="uploadFileButton" size="40"
    accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

JS:

```
$("#uploadFileButton").unbind("click").click(function() {
    //HOW can I check after browse window is closed???????
});
```

Comment: You have to do some ajax magic here. Either 1. upload file via ajax and on success, run your unbind method, or 2. run ajax method to check for file, and if true, run method.

Comment: When I mean upload..I mean after they browse for the file and click open and load the file into the browser

Comment: You don't use the `click` event, but the `change` event, then you'll get the file from the `event` object.

Comment: @adeneo.....ahhhhhhhhh that makes sense...let me try it!

Comment: `$("#uploadFileButton").change(function(){
         //submit the form here
 });`